# Change glyphicon icon color inside a datetimepicker dropdown widget

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using this [gem](https://github.com/zpaulovics/datetimepicker-rails) to get the bootsrap datetimepicker. And used the following HTML code to incorporate it:

```
<div  id="custom-dates" style=" clear:both;">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class='col-md-3 col-xs-3'>
    <div class="form-group">
            <b>From:</b>
         <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker6'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" style="margin: 0px !important;" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='col-md-3 col-xs-3'>
    <div class="form-group">
        <b>To:</b>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker7'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control"  style="margin: 0px !important;"/>
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" style="top:0;">
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Same as this: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#linked-pickers . The dropdown works fine. However, the up and down arrow to increment/decrement minute and hour does not appear. This is because the color is matching with the background. When I hover over it, the area around it turns grey so the arrow remains white but becomes visible. Same icon in the above link appears fine. How do I fix this? 
I can't hover and then take a screenshot as the dropdown goes away. I cannot even inspect the element as clicking on it hides the widget. Any suggestions to inspect the element would be welcome too.

Comment: Can you create a demo of the current output?

Comment: i think you can inspect this : https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#inline  instead of linked-picker, 
or run this script :
$('.input-group-addon').on('click', function(){ console.log($(' .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget').html());} );

, then please show your problem again.

Answer (score 1):

Change **color** to `#ff9900`:

```
.glyphicon {color: #ff9900 !important;}
```

---

Add a custom class like to make changes for certain classes

```
.myclass .glyphicon {color: #ff9900 !important;}
```